# Multi Nvidia GPU overclocking for computations (CUDA)

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have seen in forums and manuals that you have to add

```
Option "Coolbits" "value"
```

to xorg.conf or similar files.

I have been able to get this working for the first GPU, the one rendering the display. I have not been able to get overclocking options in nvidia-settings for the second GPU, not rendering any display.

I have tried things like

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Videocard0"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:2:00:0"
    Option      "Coolbits" "12"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Videocard1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:3:00:0"
    Option      "Coolbits" "12"
EndSection
```

in the various files: xorg.conf, 99-nvidia.conf, nvidia-xorg.conf. Everything I have tried has led to black screens, no overclocking capability or overclocking capability on the first GPU only.

Is it possible to unlock overclocking for both GPUs, if so how?

I have not found this question asked anywhere. I am running 346.59 drivers on Fedora 21.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No I have the slower of the two GPUs on the display so I can OC it to the level of the other GPU. I havn't found a proper solution.

Comment: I have solved it on my machine, and added an answer. Give it a try?

Comment: Had trouble because Fedora doesn't have a xorg.conf by default and the tools to generate it were giving invalid ones. Once I had a xorg.conf your method was quick to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the xorg.conf file to add virtual X servers for each of the cards (even those not connected to a monitor) solved the issue.

Basically, you want to have a server layout section with all of your real and virtual screens:

```
Section "ServerLayout"  
    Identifier    "Layout0"     
#   Our real monitor
    Screen 0      "Screen0" 0 0     
#   Our virtual monitors
    Screen 1      "Screen1"     
    Screen 2      "Screen2"
#    ....
    Screen 3      "Screen3"     
    InputDevice   "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice   "Mouse0"    "CorePointer" 
EndSection
```

Then, for each your cards, you can put in (almost) identical "Monitor", "Screen" and "Display" sections, differing only by their identifiers, which in the following are `N`, but should be repaced by the card number, `0`,`1`, etc. Note that at least the parameters for the real monitor should correspond to what you currently have in your `xorg.conf` file, i.e. in the following I have `CRT` since it's an old VGA monitor.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "ScreenN"
    Device         "DeviceN"
    Monitor        "MonitorN"
    DefaultDepth 24
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "CRT"
    Option         "Coolbits" "5"
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
       Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection



Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "MonitorN"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-N"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "DeviceN"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Your Card name here"
    BusID          "PCI:X:Y:Z"
EndSection
```

Comment: You write *Then, for each your cards, you can put in (almost) identical "Monitor", "Screen" and "Display" sections* but then you show `Screen`, `Monitor` and `Device` not `Display` sections. What's the truth?

Comment: Many thanks for the tip, I also had the same issue with overclocking settings not showing up. I managed to get my system work by adding just a screen for each device.

Comment: It can be very hard to get this to work by editing this file manually. Running this command `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration` will automatically make the changes for you to the `xorg.conf` file. Then you just need to reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: If your monitors are not attached to `Device 0`, `nvidia-xconfig` might give you a blank screen after rebooting. You can just change the identifier of the attached device to `Device 0`. And to remove the extra space caused by the virtual screens, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611876/disabling-extra-monitors-from-fake-x11-sessions/611877#611877).

Comment: I did everything but I still cannot overclock the card.

Answer (score 12):

I never was able to get it to work by hand editing xorg.conf.  What did work was to execute on the command line which sets it all up for you:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

Then edit xorg.conf.  For me that was `sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
and prepend "#" to each line containing allow-empty-initial-configuration to comment it out.

Reboot.

Then to overclock run:

```
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings
```

To restore your settings after a reboot create an executable file that you call from  startup applications containing the text below which will set the gpu clock offset and set the gpu to prefer maximum performance.  My example sets the offset to 50. Don't set the offset too high in the file for your actual display gpu until you know for sure what you want or you may end up with a system where the display won't work:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50

nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50

nvidia-settings -a [gpu:2]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:2]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50

nvidia-settings -a [gpu:3]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:3]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50
```

If you want to overclock memory too it's

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=800
```

And of related interest, you can also modify power to the cards. To see the valid values enter a value of 1000

```
sudo -n nvidia-smi -i 0 --persistence-mode=1
sudo -n nvidia-smi -i 0 --power-limit=145
```

And just to display power

```
nvidia-smi
```

Comment: This worked for me, but you do not need to comment out `Allow Empty Initial Configuration`. And if you are going to comment out these lines anyway, just run the command without the `--allow-empty-initial-configuration` parameter.

Comment: On my system I did.

Comment: If I don't comment out those lines I get duplicate icons on my panel. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

First use

```
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And write this into file

```
Section "ServerLayout"  
    Identifier    "Layout0"     
    #   Our real monitor
    Screen 0      "Screen0" 0 0     
#   Our virtual monitors
    Screen 1      "Screen1"     
    Screen 2      "Screen2"
#    ....
    Screen N      "ScreenN"  

    InputDevice   "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice   "Mouse0"    "CorePointer" 
EndSection
```

where N-1 is the number of graphic cards

save with

```
:w
```

Then use this command, to auto-fill the rest, and to unlock overclocking.

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

Then again

```
    sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and check if the GPU to whom the monitor is attached is in the first place wher N=0.

save with

```
:w
```

reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same settings to all cards, a shorthand would be:

`nvidia-settings -a GpuPowerMizerMode=1
nvidia-settings -a GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50`

Answer (score 0):

Sudo Nvidia-settings -a crashed my desktop.
I had to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf for it to work again.
I have 2 dgpus, with only 1 monitor connected