# Disabling extra monitors from "fake" X11 sessions

Tags: xorg, nvidia, display

I have 3 NVIDIA GPUs in my system. One is used for display, and two are used for compute. I would like to adjust the fan curve for the two compute GPUs, and from what I know all current methods require running a X server for the fan control to function (Some say they can turn on X, adjust fan speed and turn it back off but those never work for me).

That's ok, I turned on X without attaching monitors to them using `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration` and it works. The problem is it also introduce new "monitors" or "X Screen" that somehow became part of my working space. It is *really* annoying because my mouse would often go outside the boundary into the "fake screens".

I considered using mouse trapping script -- a program that continuously monitors and sends the mouse back to valid working space. I don't really want to waste my CPU time with it though.

I checked all the settings in `nvidia-settings` but cannot find a way to disable them.

Here is my `Xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 440.95.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option "ignore" "true"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    Option "ignore" "true"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:9:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:66:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:67:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How do I disable the extra screens?

Answer (score 0):

Better answers are definitely welcomed. I've been trying to fix this for a long time and this is the best hack that I have. The insight comes when I was randomly trying each and every setting in nvidia-setting. One warning said something like "absolute position should only be set for screen 0 or else some screens might not be reachable". Not reachable! That is exactly what I wanted!

Anyway I "moved" the extra screens far away in absolute position and everything works, only the following has to be changed.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Absolute 1000 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```